# Getting and deleting posts properly

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Can I get some help?

Index.php:

```
<form class="delete" id="delete" action="../functions/delete.php" method="POST">

    <table class="table">

        <?php
        include('../../configs/dbconfig.php');

        $sql = "SELECT id, title FROM posts";
        $posts = $connection->query($sql);
        while($row = $posts->fetch_assoc()) {
            $id = $row["id"];
            $title = $row["title"];
            ?>

            <thead class="thead-light">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    <th scope="col">Headline</th>
                    <th scole="col">Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th><?php echo $id; ?></th>
                    <td><?php echo $title; ?></td>
                    <td><button type="submit" id="btn-delete" name="submit" class="btn btn-light"><i class="fas fa-minus-circle"></i> Delete</button></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>
</form>
```

Delete.php:

```
<?php
include('../../configs/dbconfig.php');

$id = $_POST['id']; // Can I get some help?
$sql = "DELETE FROM posts WHERE id=?";
$stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
if($stmt->execute()) {
    echo "deleted";
} else {
    echo "error";
}
?>
```

It spawns ID and title of the every post and there is a button and after clicking it, it should delete the correct ID, but instead it always deletes the last one with the following code:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
```

Comment: Only the last element of the same name will be sent to php, as its value will overwrite any prior. You should probably wrap each specific button and hidden input in a form, so it does not submit ALL of the fields in one giant form regardless the button you pushed.

Comment: Keep in mind that without some kind of access control mechanism this permits anyone to delete anything from your system at any time.

Comment: If you want to access `$_POST['id']` then there has to be an `<input>` with an attribute of `name="id"` inside the form

Comment: @tadman it is used for admin control panel so it already has that kinda mechanism, just the deleting makes me confused.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I'll try to make it work.

Comment: There is literally zero access control code here. I hope this isn't security through obscurity and that the access control code is omitted for simplicity's sake. It's reasons like this why I'm a strong proponent of using frameworks as they have some kind of access-control system built in that's reliable and tested.

Comment: @tadman Well, probably. I'm beginner, but I think it's useless to be mentioned. I'll be grateful if you guys show me some similarly examples of getting&deleting data from MySQL correctly.

Comment: put you input hidden within form. Then it will post data on action page.

Comment: I'm just looking out for you here. I want your application to work well and be secure so you don't end up in the unfortunate situation of having to explain to someone why your site got hacked and all your data is gone. I'd strongly advise you to look at various development frameworks](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) or [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) and find one you really like. Use the framework's method for handling this, whatever that is, as they each have their own approach.

Comment: A framework will help you do things like *make sure your delete links are POST*. If these are GET by accident an over-eager web-caching plugin can and will delete your entire site by being "helpful" and loading all of these delete links in advance.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answers guys. Also I am familiar with laravel. I mean most of my friends use it so I've heard about it, but I've never tried it. All help is appreciated and all advices are under consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Give your button a *value* and use the `$id`:

```
<td><button type="submit" name="submit" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" id="btn-delete" class="btn btn-light"><i class="fas fa-minus-circle"></i> Delete</button></td>
```

Then use the *name* to get the *value*:

```
$id = $_POST['submit'];
```